# Sound doesn't play if audio is being recorded?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an app that makes a sound every x seconds. If I'm recording audio, it stops playing the noise, even though I can see the noise being triggered in the log/

relevant code:

```
import AVFoundation
```

-

```
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!

let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
```

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
    }
}

func startRecording() {


    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd H:m"

    let fileName = "\(df.string(from: time)).wav"
    let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    audioRecorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(url: path, settings: [:])

    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}
```

the code to play the sound:

```
let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016 //random sound id
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you imported the `AudioToolbox` framework

Comment: Just added it with no change

Comment: are you tried this in simulator or device

Comment: On device. The sound works fine when the audio is not recording

Comment: see this once may be helps you https://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/

Comment: What I had to do, even though it's shared instance, is to create a second AVAudioSession for the sound; that way they aren't stopping eachother.